# How to create a reaction on user tap on mobile with HTML, CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website, full responsive (made with Bootstrap) & available in mobile-apps with Cordova.

In mobile, the actions done by user are not really "dynamic" : when user "click (mobile tap)", user don't see if his action is done. They have to wait the end of the loading time to see if their "click" worked.

What I'm looking for : a dynamic behaviour on each "click", which makes appear for exemple a circle, to show the user that his click worked :

[image] 
In this exemple, a grey shadow appears on the user click.

Any ideas ?
Many thanks

Comment: This has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516311/drawing-a-circle-in-a-canvas-on-mouseclick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a circle in a canvas on mouseclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516311/drawing-a-circle-in-a-canvas-on-mouseclick)

Comment: Aside from drawing the circle, you should have a full understanding of asynchronous actions. When the user hits a button or something, run a wait animation *(I would use CSS animation)* or draw a circle, then when the asynchronous activity ends stop your animation *(I would add a class that does animation-play-state:paused; display:none;)*.

Comment: @MarvinKlar yes but incomplete, the link of the fiddle is dead...

Comment: @PHPglue it's sound really perfect, but how can I do this pls ? I'm a back-end dev with no js skills ... shame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using JavaScript. First, create a loading animation using HTML & CSS and hide it.

After loading the page, select all links and buttons using `document.getElementsByTagName()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`

Now create a function to show or hide the loading animation. Then loop through the elements and add click event listener to them.

HTML:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none">Loading...Please Wait</div>
```

JS:

```
var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");

function showLoading(){
    loading.style.display = "block";
}

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("click",showLoading);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Adnan, sorry i'm pretty new in JS, and don't think i'm understand. I put the div and the script but it's not working : "Loading..." don't appears

Comment: You have to use the JS codes in window.onload function. Post the codes here, so that we can understand what's the problem...:)

Comment: Hi @Gdebrig, try again. I made a mistake in the code. I have fixed it. Please try again now.

Comment: I searched on the web for the "window.onload" (didn't knew what it was) and its works perfectly for the loading alert. Thanks. But for the circle on mouse click, do you have ideas ? Thanks

Comment: window.onload function starts executing after rendering the page. The syntax is window.onload = function(){/*Your JS code goes here*/}.

Comment: You can create a circle using html and css instead of the 'Loading...Please wait' div. Then update the position of the div according to the cursor position.

Comment: Yes perfect implementation many thanks!! Last question : with Bootstrap, you have a component named "Tab". It's working with a "a" tag too. And so, your code is running when we click on a tab... Do you have a way to disabled this action on Bootstrap Tabs - Maybe a CSS class that I add on disabled items ? Thks

Comment: You can replace the line loading.style.display="block" with: if(!e.target.href.endsWith("#")){
     loading.style.display = "block";
    }

Comment: returns me : Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined :/

Comment: Also replace the line "function showLoading(){" with: function showLoading(e){